# Is there a way to create an option on an HTML form to allow a user to select exactly 2 of n choices?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to build an HTML form. For one of the questions, I want the user to be able to select exactly two choices.

I tried building two radio questions (which I understand only accept one choice) with the same 4 options, but I don't want the user to be able to select the same option twice.

```html
<form action = "\new" method = post target="_blank" id="form">
<option>Option 1</option><br>
Question 1:
<input type="radio" name="S1" value = 0 checked>C1<br>
<input type="radio" name="S1" value = 1>C2<br>
<input type="radio" name="S1" value = 2>C3<br>
<input type="radio" name="S1" value = 3>C4<br>
<br>
Question 2:
<input type="radio" name="S2" value = 0 checked>C1<br>
<input type="radio" name="S2" value = 1>C2<br>
<input type="radio" name="S2" value = 2>C3<br>
<input type="radio" name="S2" value = 3>C4<br>
</form>
//I want the form to output (S1,S2), but S1 cannot equal S2
```

With this code, the user can still choose the same choice for both questions. How do I fix this?

Comment: You'd need JavaScript for that

Comment: How do I do that with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added this JavaScript at the bottom of the HTML document.

```
<script>
function validate(){
    var C1 = Number($("input[name='S1']:checked").val());
    var C2 = Number($("input[name='S2']:checked").val());
    if (C1==C2){
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
function init(){
    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = validate;
}
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Hope this helps anyone else who was struggling like me!